# Code formatting when using pointers

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there any reason why the asterisk is next to the object type in this code? I'm a little confused by the way I see this used. Some times it looks like this:

```
NSString* stringBefore;
```

and sometimes like this:

```
NSString *stringBefore;
```

Is there  a difference? Or a right or wrong way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452335/asterisk-sometimes-on-variable-type-sometimes-on-variable-name-why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes no difference.

It just just an indicator to how well versed the author is in writing and reading Objective-C.  The traditional standard is to write it as:

```
NSString *stringBefore;
```

Comment: You can be well versed and choose not to follow the standard.

Comment: That makes total sense to me, until the author does one of these:
UISwitch *whichSwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
The parenthesis kind of throw it for me. Why is the asterisk grouped with the type?

Comment: Because it is part of the type - as in, a "pointer to a NSString". And programmers who don't follow standards are called "bad programmers" - unless they have good reason, of course.

Answer (score 10):

I use the `*` near the variable name and not the type, since if you declare something like:

```
int *i, j;
```

`i` will be a pointer to `int`, and j will be a `int`.

If you used the other syntax:

```
int* i, j;
```

you may think that both `i` and `j` are pointers when they are not.

That said, I don't use nor recommend declaring a pointer and a non-pointer variable in the same line, as in this sample.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference.